# function not entering a loop

Tags: java, arrays, function, vector

Hi i'm trying to program a tool that allow us to manage a small shop , i've managed to get evey functionality to work`but this last function is getting me crazy

```java
public void ajoutCommandesCli() {
    Commandes com = new Commandes();
    Magasin m = this;
    Client c = new Client();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("quel est votre numero client ?");
    int numcli = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("testosterone");
    System.out.println(this.listecli.capacity());
    for (int i = 0; i <= this.listecli.size(); i++) {
        if (numcli == listecli.get(i).num) {
            int index = this.listecli.indexOf(i);
            c = this.listecli.get(index);
            System.out.println("test aaaa");
            com.saisirCommandes(this, c);
        } else {
            System.out.println("réessayer?");
            System.out.println("1-oui");
            System.out.println("2-non");
            int choix = sc.nextInt();
            if (choix == 1) {
                this.ajoutCommandesCli();
            } else {
                System.out.println("testitestos");
                MenuMagasin.afficherMenu(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this function doesnt even enter the first for loop and i dont know why .
Magasin has a vector of client ,but java tells me my vector capacity is 10 but the teacher told us vector just has no definite capacity , i havent inputed any lenghth for the vector.this is getting me crazy please help me guys .I'm sorry if my question sounds stupid but i need help.

Comment: Please don't use a `Vector` use `ArrayList` instead. Also `capacity` is different than `size`. `Capacity` is how many elements the `vector` can hold before it needs to resize, `size` is the current number of elements in the `vector`.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger in your IDE? That will answer the question for you when you see the value of listecli at runtime.

Comment: thank you guys ArrayList did worked for me .muchos gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks information, you should make a *minimal-reproducible-example* as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

I'd recommend running your program in debug mode, and view the value of this expression :

```
numcli==listecli.get(i).num
```

- does your program ever run the `if` statement's code ?
- is you list `listecli` empty ?
- what's the error message you getting ?